# Why git keep reporting errors

Tags: git

You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.

```
git remote add origin ...
error: remote origin already exists.

git push origin master

Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Comment: `git remote add origin` => `error: remote origin already exists` => didn't add a new version of `origin` because it couldn't because `origin` is already set up. Did you want to rename or delete `origin` first? Or did you want to just change the URL stored under the existing named `origin`?

Comment: I want to push the master branch of the local warehouse to the remote warehouse

Comment: A *remote* is a name used for several purposes. The main purpose is to store a URL. You can create as many remotes as you like; each one stores a URL. Once created, you can't create a new remote with the same name as the existing remote—but you can *delete* a remote, or *change its URL*. You just can't add a *new* remote with the *same name*. (I'm guessing perhaps English is not your first language...?)

Comment: Thank you, I understand, my English is not good

Answer (score 0):

1. if you want to try remove or rename origin
   `git remote rm origin` for removing origin and can try adding it again
   `git remote rename origin oldorigin` for renaming and can try adding origin again
2. as per your error you might need to create a new ssh file
   by running `ssh-keygen -t rsa`
   and update in your github/or any git server account.